# Extreme value theorem in practice

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a continious function with $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=0=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)$.

Show that the function is limited and that the function f takes its own inf and sup, i.e. there is an $x\in \Bbb R$ with $f(x)=$inf$_{y\in \Bbb R}f(y)$ or an $x\in \Bbb R$ with $f(x)=$ sup$_{y \in \Bbb R}f(y).$

I was able to show that the function is bounded above and below by using the extreme value theorem, but then I'm a bit lost on the second part of the question. Do i need to consider all 3 cases (sup or inf < 0 and sup or inf >0 and sup=inf=0) I was wondering how else to prove that? Any hint would be appreciated!!

Comment: Note you can't have $\inf f > 0$ or $\sup f < 0$, due to the horizontal asymptotes. You should consider the cases, $\inf f = \sup f = 0$ (easy: $f$ must be constant), $\inf f < 0$, and $\sup f > 0$. Note, the last two cases are not mutually exclusive, but this is not a problem!

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you!!!  The case where inf $f$=sup$f$=0 is quite easy, then ive been working the case where sup $f>0$. But then i realised for there to be such an x, the sequence $x_n\in \Bbb R$ have to be limited as well? Since for all $x\in \Bbb R$ we can find an $\epsilon$ such that $|f(x)-f(t)|<\epsilon$ for all $|x-t|<\delta$...But how do i show that there is an $x$ =0? Can i use the mean value theorem?

Comment: If you have a sequence $x_n$ so that $f(x_n) \to \sup f > 0$, then indeed the sequence must be bounded. You'll have to use the definitions of the limits $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$, $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$. Try considering $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}\sup f > 0$ in all three limit definitions to show that the sequence $x_n$ must eventually be within two bounds (one defined by the limit as $x \to \infty$ and the other defined by the limit as $x \to -\infty$).